# How to identify a "default member" in a COM library?

Tags: c#, com

I'm using the `ITypeInfo` API to "translate" COM type libraries into "declaration" objects that my application uses.

One of the features of a "declaration" is "attributes" - I'm able to tell when a property "declaration" should have a `{name}.VB_UserMemId = -4` attribute (i.e. when it's a `_NewEnum` non-browsable property; I'm also able to tell when a property is hidden.

What I'm failing to tell, is when a member is the *default member* for the type. According to the description of `FUNCFLAG_FDEFAULTBIND` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221143(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> *The function that best represents the object. Only one function in a type information can have this attribute.*

...this sounds very very much like what I'm looking for. However among all the members I'm iterating across a handful of type libraries (including the VBA standard library and the entire Excel object model), exactly **none** have that flag on.

I'm expecting this code to call `AddDefaultMemberAttribute` for things like `Collection.Item`, which is the type's *default member* - but no dice. Am I not checking the correct flag/value?

```
var attributes = new Attributes();
if (((FUNCFLAGS)memberDescriptor.wFuncFlags) != 0)
{
    if (memberName == "_NewEnum" && ((FUNCFLAGS)memberDescriptor.wFuncFlags).HasFlag(FUNCFLAGS.FUNCFLAG_FNONBROWSABLE))
    {
        attributes.AddEnumeratorMemberAttribute(memberName);
    }
    else if (((FUNCFLAGS)memberDescriptor.wFuncFlags).HasFlag(FUNCFLAGS.FUNCFLAG_FHIDDEN))
    {
        attributes.AddHiddenMemberAttribute(memberName);
    }
    else if (((FUNCFLAGS)memberDescriptor.wFuncFlags).HasFlag(FUNCFLAGS.FUNCFLAG_FDEFAULTBIND))
    {
        // bug: none of the 30K+ reflected members have this flag on??
        attributes.AddDefaultMemberAttribute(memberName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default property is the one with dispid 0.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it possible that this would be the `memberDescriptor.memid` value? All members I'm picking up with `memid=0` are hidden members called `_Default` that return either a `VT_HRESULT`, a `VT_PTR`, or a `VT_DISPATCH` ...I guess I'm not quite close to getting to `Collection.Item` or `TextBox.Text`...

Comment: Probably, the return types sound fairly screwy.  Use Oleview.exe to compare to what you get, use File + View TypeLib.  It decompiles the type library like you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the check for `wFuncFlags != 0`, you're skipping a ton of members with that check, a lot of which you're actually interested in.

Now check for `memid == 0` ([thanks @HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041181/how-to-identify-a-default-member-in-a-com-library#comment59732405_36041181))

```
else if (memberDescriptor.memid == 0)
{
    attributes.AddDefaultMemberAttribute(memberName);
    Debug.WriteLine("Default member found: {0}.{1} ({2} / {3})", moduleDeclaration.IdentifierName, memberName, memberDeclarationType, (VarEnum)memberDescriptor.elemdescFunc.tdesc.vt);
}
```

This little `Debug.WriteLine` instruction produces this output (truncated, to fit post character limit):

```
Default member found: _ErrObject.Number (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: _ErrObject.Number (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: _Collection.Item (Function / VT_VARIANT)
Default member found: Adjustments.Item (PropertyGet / VT_R4)
Default member found: Adjustments.Item (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: ColorFormat.RGB (PropertyGet / VT_USERDEFINED)
Default member found: ColorFormat.RGB (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: ShapeNodes.Item (Function / VT_PTR)
Default member found: DiagramNodes.Item (Function / VT_PTR)
Default member found: DiagramNodeChildren.Item (Function / VT_PTR)
Default member found: IWindows._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: _Application._Default (PropertyGet / VT_BSTR)
Default member found: IRange._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IRange._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: Sheets._Default (PropertyGet / VT_DISPATCH)
Default member found: IHPageBreaks._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IVPageBreaks._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IRecentFiles._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IStyle._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IStyles._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IBorders._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IAddIns._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IToolbars._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IToolbarButtons._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IAreas._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: Workbooks._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: IMenuBars._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IMenus._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IMenuItems._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICharts._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDrawingObjects._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDrawingObjects._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotCaches._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotFormula._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotFormula._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotFormulas._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotTable._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotTable._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotField._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotField._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICalculatedFields._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotItem._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotItem._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICalculatedItems._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDialogs._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICheckBox._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICheckBox._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICheckBoxes._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICheckBoxes._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IOptionButton._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IOptionButton._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IOptionButtons._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IOptionButtons._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IScrollBar._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IScrollBar._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IScrollBars._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IScrollBars._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListBox._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListBox._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListBoxes._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListBoxes._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDropDown._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDropDown._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDropDowns._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDropDowns._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISpinner._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISpinner._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISpinners._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISpinners._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPanes._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IGroupObject._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IGroupObject._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IGroupObjects._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IGroupObjects._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IModules._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDialogSheets._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IWorksheets._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: INames._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IName._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IChartObjects._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICustomViews._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IFormatConditions._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IComments._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IQueryTables._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IParameters._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IODBCErrors._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IHyperlinks._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IFilters._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IChartColorFormat._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IAxes._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPoints._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISeriesCollection._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IDataLabels._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ILegendEntries._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ITrendlines._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IShapes._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IShapeRange._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IGroupShapes._Default (Function / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IControlFormat._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IControlFormat._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPublishObjects._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IOLEDBErrors._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPhonetics._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: CubeFields._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: IUsedObjects._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICustomProperties._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICustomProperty._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICalculatedMembers._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ICalculatedMember._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IWatches._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IErrors._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISmartTagAction._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISmartTagActions._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISmartTag._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISmartTags._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISmartTagRecognizer._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISmartTagRecognizers._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotItemList._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IAllowEditRanges._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IUserAccessList._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListObjects._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListObject._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListColumns._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListColumn._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListRows._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXmlNamespace._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXmlNamespaces._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXmlDataBinding._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXmlSchemas._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXmlMap._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXmlMaps._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IListDataFormat._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IXPath._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotLineCells._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotLines._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotFilters._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IWorkbookConnection._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IWorkbookConnection._Default (PropertyLet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IConnections._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISheetViews._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IActions._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IColorScaleCriteria._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IIconCriteria._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IIconSet._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IIconSets._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IRanges._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPages._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IServerViewableItems._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ITableStyleElements._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ITableStyle._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ITableStyles._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISortFields._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IColorStops._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IFileExportConverters._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IAddIns2._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISparklineGroups._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IPivotTableChangeList._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISlicerCaches._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISlicerCacheLevels._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISlicers._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISlicerItems._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: ISlicerPivotTables._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IProtectedViewWindows._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: IProtectedViewWindow._Default (PropertyGet / VT_HRESULT)
Default member found: Windows._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Range._Default (PropertyGet / VT_VARIANT)
Default member found: Range._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: HPageBreaks._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: VPageBreaks._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: RecentFiles._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Style._Default (PropertyGet / VT_BSTR)
Default member found: Styles._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Borders._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: AddIns._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Toolbars._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: ToolbarButtons._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Areas._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: MenuBars._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Menus._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: MenuItems._Default (PropertyGet / VT_DISPATCH)
Default member found: Charts._Default (PropertyGet / VT_DISPATCH)
Default member found: DrawingObjects._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: DrawingObjects._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: PivotCaches._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: PivotFormula._Default (PropertyGet / VT_BSTR)
Default member found: PivotFormula._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: PivotFormulas._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: PivotTable._Default (PropertyGet / VT_BSTR)
Default member found: PivotTable._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: PivotField._Default (PropertyGet / VT_BSTR)
Default member found: PivotField._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: CalculatedFields._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: PivotItem._Default (PropertyGet / VT_BSTR)
Default member found: PivotItem._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: CalculatedItems._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: Dialogs._Default (PropertyGet / VT_PTR)
Default member found: CheckBox._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: CheckBox._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: CheckBoxes._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: CheckBoxes._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: OptionButton._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: OptionButton._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: OptionButtons._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: OptionButtons._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: ScrollBar._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: ScrollBar._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: ScrollBars._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: ScrollBars._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: ListBox._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: ListBox._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: ListBoxes._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: ListBoxes._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: DropDown._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: DropDown._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: DropDowns._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: DropDowns._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: Spinner._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: Spinner._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
Default member found: Spinners._Default (PropertyGet / VT_I4)
Default member found: Spinners._Default (PropertyLet / VT_VOID)
...
```

So, you get the `Collection.Item` and `ErrObject.Number` that you're after. The [other] question is now, how to get the name of the member that this `_Default` thing is pointing to, for pretty much every other default member out there.

But it's a start.